# CMIS / Chemistry / Alfresco: appending content failure recovery

Tags: alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I have to upload very large files (> 10 GB) to an Alfresco repository from a Java web application. Due to file size, I'd like to use a chunked upload (say 1 GB at time), using the `appendContentStream` action (CMIS 1.1), provided in Java by Apache Chemistry.

My question is: how to recover from a failed chunk upload? AFAIU, one of points in using `appendContentStream` is to avoid to re-upload the whole file in case of failure, but I did not find any mechanism to say: *"OK, last chunk gone wrong, let's upload it again"*. How to avoid corrupted files in case of chunk upload failure?

Looking at the Alfresco source code [1] and [2], I see that in 4.2f a new minor version is create on each chunk append, while in 5 this is not true anymore. Both solutions are subobtimal, to me (in 4.2f there is "versions pollution" and in 5 I cannot see a recovery path).

Any advice on the best pattern to follow?

[1] (master) https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/24ae86da33534a90fc10a693f48bc45556fd9d9d/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/opencmis/CMISConnector.java#L1816

[2] (4.2f) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alfresco/community-edition/V4.2f/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/opencmis/CMISConnector.java